# Setting a TextView in an Inner Static Class - Android

Tags: java, android, textview

I am currently editing the AprilTags code from GitHub found here: https://github.com/johnjwang/apriltag-android/tree/master/src/main. I am trying to set a TextView in an inner static class.

```
static class LinesProgram {
    private static final String vertexShaderCode =
            "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;\n" +
            "attribute vec4 aPosition;\n" +
            "void main() {\n" +
            "    gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * aPosition;\n" +
            "}\n";

    private static final String fragmentShaderCode =
            "precision mediump float;\n" +
            "uniform vec4 uColor;\n" +
            "void main() {\n" +
            "    gl_FragColor = uColor;\n" +
            "}\n";

    private FloatBuffer buffer;
    private Context context;

    int programId;

    int aPositionLoc;
    int uMVPMatrixLoc;
    int uColorLoc;

    public LinesProgram(Context context) {
        // Compile the shader code into a GL program
        this.context = context;
        int vid = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderCode);
        int fid = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderCode);
        programId = GLES20.glCreateProgram();
        checkGlError("glCreateProgram");
        GLES20.glAttachShader(programId, vid);
        checkGlError("glAttachShader");
        GLES20.glAttachShader(programId, fid);
        checkGlError("glAttachShader");
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(programId);
        int[] linkStatus = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGetProgramiv(programId, GLES20.GL_LINK_STATUS, linkStatus, 0);
        if (linkStatus[0] != GLES20.GL_TRUE) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not link program: ");
            Log.e(TAG, GLES20.glGetProgramInfoLog(programId));
            GLES20.glDeleteProgram(programId);
        }

        // Get handles to attributes and uniforms
        aPositionLoc = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(programId, "aPosition");
        checkGlError("get aPosition");
        uMVPMatrixLoc = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programId, "uMVPMatrix");
        checkGlError("get uMVPMatrix");
        uColorLoc = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programId, "uColor");
        checkGlError("get uColor");
    }

    // points = [x0 y0 x1 y1 ...]
    // npoints = number of xy pairs in points (e.g. points is expected to have
    //           a length of at least 2*npoints)
    public void draw(float[] PVM, float[] points, int npoints, float[] rgba, int type) {
        // Reuse points buffer if possible
        if (buffer == null || 2*npoints > buffer.capacity()) {
            int nbytes = 4 * 2*npoints;
            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(nbytes);
            bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            buffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
        }
        buffer.position(0);
        buffer.put(points, 0, 2*npoints);
        buffer.position(0);

        GLES20.glUseProgram(programId);
        checkGlError("glUseProgram");

        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(uMVPMatrixLoc, 1, false, PVM, 0);
        checkGlError("glUniformMatrix4fv");

        GLES20.glUniform4fv(uColorLoc, 1, rgba, 0);
        checkGlError("glUniform4fv");

        // Render frame
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(aPositionLoc);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(aPositionLoc, 2,
                GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 8, buffer);

        GLES20.glLineWidth(4.0f);
        GLES20.glDrawArrays(type, 0, npoints);

        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(aPositionLoc);
        GLES20.glUseProgram(0);

        TextView coordinates = (TextView) ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        //for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        //    coordinates.setText(String.valueOf(points[i]));
        //}

    }
}
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.app.Activity.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
```

and the app crashes when it gets to where I set the TextView.

I'm sure the text view id is the same as defined in the main.xml file. The TextView is within a FrameLayout if that is important.

In the onCreate function I defined at the top, `public TextView coordinates;`.

Comment: The context that you pass in your constructor is probably null

Comment: No maybe, that's the only way it can happen.

Comment: I understand that there is something that is null, but it is not helpful to just say the error is that. I'm new to Android so I'm looking for an explanation as to what is null and why I need to instantiate it. I thought I instantiated everything I need.

Comment: @GVillani82 how do I set my context so it is not null?

Comment: I have no idea: I don't see the part of your code where you pass the context to the constructor